# Create bash script with dependency

Tags: macos, bash, unix, terminal, command

I want to create a small bash script with a dependency if you don't have one of the commands installed on the machine, I want to install it.

The command I'm dependent on is `json` from `npm install json -g`.

So what I'm looking for is something like this:

```
checkcommand json --if `echo `"all good"` --else `npm install json -g`
```

Is there anything like this for mac terminal?

Comment: did you test with `which` ?  something like  `which json && echo "json is installed" || echo "not installed, installing..."`

Answer (score 0):

You can implement `checkcommand` with the built-in command `hash`:

```
checkcommand () {
    # Clear the command's location from the cache...
    hash -d "$1"
    # ... then force the shell to look for it again
    hash "$1" 2> /dev/null
}

if ! checkcommand json; then
    npm install json -g
fi
```